# Eclipse syntax analysis scope exlusion pattern not working

Tags: eclipse, code-analysis, static-analysis, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse's syntax analysis tool in my CDT project and getting some errors (related to known [Eclipse bugs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Eclipse_CDT#Headers_are_only_parsed_once)) that I would like not to see. For that I'm trying to use the tool [customization](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis#Customize) exclusion patterns, but can't get them to work.

Here is my environment:

- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, **Version**: Juno Service Release 1, **Build id**: 20120920-0800
- Ubuntu Linux 10.10

In my project's properties-> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis -> (Use project settings) [my kind of error] Customize Selected -> Scope -> Exclusion patterns (add...) I have used every pattern I could think of to exclude the files.

For example, being my file under src/SomeFolder/SomeFile.cpp, I tried:

- `**/SomeFile.cpp`
- `**/SomeFile*`
- `src/SomeFolder/SomeFile.cpp`
- `SomeFolder/SomeFile.cpp`

But none seems to work. Any clue about how can I exclude the specific errors in the specific files? (note I would like to keep the errors check in those files that don't present the bogus error report).